# What is English for "первый блин комом"?

Tags: перевод, idioms

What is a idiomatic English (US) equivalent of Russian "`первый блин комом`" (meaning that you cannot expect perfect results on the first try)?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking for a phrase in English.  Please post such questions to English.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: Practice makes perfect!

Answer (score 4):

you must spoil before you spin (well)

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)`practice makes perfect (lit: first pancake is always a blob)`

Comment: This is not well-used phrase in US English. Use Jacob's comment.